# CI Active Record Query not updating

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Am trying to update `tenders` table in my db but for some reasons its updating the table with zeros.
After getting the `last_query()` string and running it from `phpmyadmin` window it updates successfully but using active records it does not.
Other queries are working properly apart from this.

What might be the problem with my code?

Here is my code

```
$data=array(
'tender_type_type_id' => $this->input->post('tender_type_id'),
                        'Description' =>  $this->input->post('tdescription'),
                        'obtaining_documents' => $this->input->post('obtaining_docs'),
                        'submission_process' => $this->input->post('submission_proc'),
                        'obtaining_documents' => $this->input->post('obtaining_docs'),
                        'applicationfee' => $this->input->post('applicationfee'),
                        'Location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                        'WebLink' => $this->input->post('url'),
                        'clossing_date' => $this->input->post('endson'),
                        'opening_date' => $this->input->post('openedon'),
                        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                        'publication_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
                        'attachments' => $this->input->post('upload'),
                        'Organization_OrganizationID' => $this->input->post('organizationid'),
                        'tender_category_category_id' => $this->input->post('categoryid'),
                        'Towns_TownID' => $this->input->post('townid'),
                        'Accounts_AccountID' =>$this->input->post('accountid'),
                        'tender_status_status_id' => $this->input->post('tender_status_id'),
                        'Location' => $this->input->post('location'),
                        'clossing_date' => $this->input->post('endson'),
                        'opening_date' => $this->input->post('openedon'));

            $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
            $this->db->where('TenderID',$id);
            $this->db->update('tenders',$data);
            return print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

Comment: $id=$this->uri->segment(3); part should be in the controller's function.And rest of the code should be in the model except the post parts.It's not working because for the id, the value is becoming null.

Comment: @BuddhiEashwarage when you var_dump $id it has the correct value. So that means using it in the model still works fine

Comment: But last_query() is just the one that was processed, so...

Comment: Please instead of `last_query` use profiler: `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` I bet that you will find error in seconds.

Comment: Could you add  snag of the table structure of this db

Comment: I found the error. My browser was updating twice. After resetting it everything now works